# CSS to recreate the effect of a phosphor-based terminal screen

Tags: css, textview

Can CSS make the effect of the slightly-fuzzy glowing text seen on green-on-black/amber-on-black [cathode-ray tube (CRT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode-ray_tube) screens to recreate the look of [computer terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal)?